# Using probability of camera flash interval to get the probability density equation in Griffith's Quantum Mechanics book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, calculus, statistics

In Griffith's QM, example 1 chapter 1, what is the intuition behind using the probability of camera flash interval to get the probability density equation in terms of "dx".

Griffith says that evidently 
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}
$$
which is not so evident for me,

how does the probability of camera flashing get the probability density in terms of "dx"

$$
\frac{dt}{T}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}dx
$$
I am having a tough time digesting the logic

Comment: It might be better to copy the relevant passage from Griffiths' text so that those w/o the book might be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Griffiths' explanation is indeed a bit lacking, but it isn't hard to see what he's doing.

First, let's consider an alternative way to solve the problem. Let $T$ be the amount of time the ball spends in the air. Then, 
$$x(t) = \frac 1 2 g t^2 \rightarrow h = \frac 1 2 g T^2 \rightarrow T = \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$

Since the probability of a sample being taken in any time between $t$ and  $t + dt$ is constant and since the probability that a given sample occurs sometime between $t = 0$ and $t = T$ must be $1$, we have

$$\rho (t)dt = \frac 1 T dt.$$

Now, to find the average of $x$ over this time interval, we take (Equation 1.9 from Section 1.1 in *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, 2nd ed.)
$$\langle x\rangle=\int_0^T x(t)\rho(t)dt = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2}gt^2\frac 1 T dt = \frac{gT^2}{6} = \frac h 3.$$

Griffiths, instead of doing this, chose to make a change of the integration variable from $t$ to $x$. Again, 
$$x = \frac 1 2 g t^2 \rightarrow dx = g t dt \rightarrow \frac {dx} {gtT} = \frac{dt}{T}.$$
Substitiuing in $t$ and $T$ gives, 
$$\frac{dt}{T} = \frac {dx} {g} \sqrt{\frac{g}{2x}\frac{g}{2h}} = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{hx}} \rightarrow \rho(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}},$$
as needed. This gives the same answer. I don't know why Griffiths wanted to do it like this, though. Perhaps he wanted to keep things consistent with working in $x$.

Comment: yes thanks i see it now 
$$
\frac{\partial t}{T} = \rho(t) = \frac{\partial x}{gtT}
$$
$$
\rho(t = \sqrt{\frac{2x}{g}})
$$
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{\partial x}{\sqrt{4hx}}

$$

as what you said quote "perhaps griffiths wanted to keep things consistent with his equations [16],[17],[18],[19] which all seem to be described in terms of position rather then time " probably explains it